# Super Slow __vdso_gettimeofday

Tags: kernel, performance, glibc

I noticed that my **__vdso_gettimeofday** function consumes way too much computation time. When running a program on my system the program spends **40s reading the time**, while my work system spends 0.037s. Even though my system runs a much bigger CPU, the computation time is by a factor **100 slower**. The difference in computation time was evaluated using the linux perf tool, i.e., perf -F 99 python test.py.

Additionally, I verified that both systems are calling the same system call's using strace. As expected the gettimeofday system call does not show up there due to vdso usage.

Both systems are running the same Ubuntu Kernel (16.04, Kernel 4.4.0-98-generic x86_64), have the same libc.so (GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu9). My problem causing system has an Intel Skylake i7 7800X running the newest microcode and Bios. Therefore, it cannot be caused by this [multithreading bug](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2017/06/msg00308.html). The CPU behaves normally in other Benchmarks, the overall performance seems fine.

**Therefore, I ran out of ideas** of causes for this performance bottleneck.

1. So do you have any ideas, what should be investigated?
2. Can this defect be only caused by an Hardware defect? -> NO!
3. Did somebody experience a similar problem or has a similar system?
4. Could a Distro upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04 help? -> YES!

---

**Edit:**
An Distro upgrade to 17.04 resolved the problem. However, it would still be interesting if this is a Bug in the 16.04 Kernel, which is specific to Intel Skylake CPU's.

Could anybody with an Skylake CPU try to recreate this issue?